# ProGet Maven Repository Feed API Access

Tags: java, maven, deployment, proget

I am attempting to publish maven builds to a ProGet feed using an API key from a Jenkins server.  However, I continue to get an Unauthorized response from the ProGet server.  I have my repository setup in my settings.xml file as such:

```
            <repository>
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <name>ProGet Snapshots</name>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                </snapshots>
                <url>https://proget.domain.com/maven2/snapshots?key=00000000000</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
            </repository>
```

Is there something wrong with my maven settings, or an authentication problem on ProGet?

Many thanks.

Comment: What version of ProGet? There were many auth-related errors (mostly regressions) in earlier 5.1.x versions

Comment: The version is 5.1.16

Answer (score 0):

From the Proget Q&A page, I finally discovered that you set the repository configuration to:

`<username>api</username>`
`<password>API_KEY</password>`

in the settings.xml file.